# How to give reference to used programming files in my thesis?

Tags: cross-referencing, logos

I am writing my thesis and I use a programming language to do the analysis of my empirical part in my thesis. I give interpretations, tables and graphics according to the code in the programming files. Now, I want to give reference to this files in my master thesis, whenever I interpret the results or show graphics, which were generated by these files. Sometimes it is just one file, sometimes more than one file. In the text, I could use the margins to give reference to the files. In the graphics and tables, I could include it in the caption. However, I wanted to ask, if there is a professional solution for this problem. I would like to create a designes reference, e.g. see [this](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/sfehtmlframe64.html): Under a table, they give reference to the .xpl file with a self-created logo:
[image: sl]

I am aware of the fact, that the design of the logo itself I have to do with a graphical tool, but how can I implement this logo with the filename in a professional way? It does NOT need to be a hyperlink or active link.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking. What would count as an answer to your question? You want to include references to external files, but "in a professional way". What does that mean?

Comment: If you have the logo/icon that you want already saved on your computer, then [[this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics)] tells you how to include it as a picture in your document. You can set the filename in a fixed-width font, as in your example, by issuing `\texttt{SFEBiTree.xpl}` next to the icon.

Comment: Also, you can put stuff in the margin `\marginpar{like so}`.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, an XploRe Screenshot! Are you using it? (I spent a lot of time dealing with it...)

EDIT: I just added the `attachfile` package and created the `\codeattach` command. It inserts the given file from the source into the PDF container. In Adobe Acrobat (Reader) you will be able to click the link and open the file, see the second screenshot.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\newcommand{\code}{{\protect\raisebox{-0.13em}{\protect\includegraphics{sql_fileextension.pdf}}}}

\newcommand{\codeattach}[1]{\textattachfile{#1}{\code~\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}


\newcommand{\insertsql}[2]{\lstinputlisting[language={SQL},caption={\code~#1, #2},label={#1}] {#1}}

\begin{document}

\insertsql{test.sql}{some basic SQL Code}


\noindent See Listing \ref{test.sql}

\codeattach{test.sql}

\end{document}
```

[image: acrobat]

Comment: haha^^ u studied what I am studying now^^ Aber die haben xplore eingestellt, vermutlich denke ich mal, weil es sich gegen R nicht durchsetzen kann. War xplore eigentlich jemals kommerziell erfolgreich?

Comment: mal ne andere Frage: Wo hast Du promoviert? Also an der HU auch? Über welches Programm und welchen Lehrstuhl?

Comment: aber wie hält man Härdle fünf Jahre lang aus? Oder war er damals nicht so? Die SFM2 Vorlesung ist/war grauenvoll, man hat überhaupt nichts gelernt, er hält keine vernünftigen Vorlesungen und seine Mitarbeiter sind auch nicht viel besser? Er selbst ist zudem noch extrem unhöflich und rabiat seinen eigenen Mitarbeitern gegenüber?